# JSON Data is not comming correctly in Jersay web service

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey

I am trying to get the response in the Jersey web service in both JSON format fo that i am using application/json as media type for @Produces

```
@produces( application/json )
```

My Data sample is comming like this

But in JSON its not comming correctly as expected:

```
  {"menu": [
      {
      "menuId": "1",
      "menuName": "Menu 1",
      "subMenu":       [
                  {
            "subMenuId": "1",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
         },
                  {
            "subMenuId": "2",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 2"
         },
                  {
            "subMenuId": "3",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 3"
         }
      ]
   },
      {
      "menuId": "2",
      "menuName": "Menu 2"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "3",
      "menuName": "Menu 3"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "4",
      "menuName": "Menu 4"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "5",
      "menuName": "Menu 5",
      "subMenu":       {
         "subMenuId": "4",
         "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
      }
   },
      {
      "menuId": "6",
      "menuName": "Menu 6"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "7",
      "menuName": "Menu 7"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "8",
      "menuName": "Menu 8",
      "subMenu":       {
         "subMenuId": "5",
         "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
      }
   },
      {
      "menuId": "9",
      "menuName": "Menu 9"
   },
      {
      "menuId": "10",
      "menuName": "Menu 10",
      "subMenu":       {
         "subMenuId": "6",
         "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
      }
   }
]}
```

As you can observe that the places where submenu data length is 1 its returning like wrong

```
{
      "menuId": "8",
      "menuName": "Menu 8",
      ***"subMenu":       {
         "subMenuId": "5",
         "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
      }***
```

Class structure

```
   class Menus{
  List<Menu> menu;
}

    class Menu{
        Long menuId;
        String menuName;
     List<SubMenu> subMenu;
    }

    class SubMenu{
       Long subMenuId;
    String subMenuName;
    }
```

I am using proper

> @XmlRootElement

above class and `@XmlElement` above setters

For XML output the data is comming as expected but in case of JSON where the List length is eqaual to 1 then only i am getting the data inside the {} brackets but its should be expected to come inside the [] brackets as like:

```
{
      "menuId": "1",
      "menuName": "Menu 1",
      "subMenu":       [
                  {
            "subMenuId": "1",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 1"
         },
                  {
            "subMenuId": "2",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 2"
         },
                  {
            "subMenuId": "3",
            "subMenuName": "Sub Menu 3"
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Do you've any object mappers with custom properties set in your jersey application config?

Comment: @BandiKishore Kishore No i don't have

Comment: Are you using Jackson as your json converter?

Comment: @BandiKishore i am using jersay-bundle and jersay-server jackson i have included but the result was same. Its working when the list length is more the one but when the list length is one its not converting correctly

Comment: Can you add a custom objectmapper and set this explicitly `WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED` to false?

Comment: @BandiKishore yes i can do it for sure but can you please give me a link how to set it because i have not idea where and how to set it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132642/discussion-between-bandi-kishore-and-rohitesh).

Answer (score 2):

The output you're seeing is called [BadgerFish](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED) way of handling JSON, when a single element is present in the Array or List.

Just try using Jackson for your Json conversion, which by default has BadgerFish disabled.

Add in your **Web.xml**:

```
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

PS : This is for Jersey 1.8 version alone. (Basically 2.x and below)

Comment: @Rohitesh Great! can you accept the answer and close out the question?